# pandas concatenate multiple columns together with pipe while skip the empty values

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

hi I want to concatenate multiple columns together using pipes as connector in pandas python and if the columns is blank values then skip this columns.

I tried the following code, it does not skip the values when its empty, it will still have a '|' to connect with other fields, what I want is the completely pass the empty field ..

for example: currently it gives me 'N|911|WALLACE|AVE||||MT|031|000600'

while I want 'N|911|WALLACE|AVE|MT|031|000600'

```
df['key'] = df[['fl_predir','fl_prim_range','fl_prim_name','fl_addr_suffix','fl_postdir','fl_unit_desig','fl_sec_range','fl_st','fl_fips_county','blk']].agg('|'.join, axis=1)
```

can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols = ['fl_predir','fl_prim_range','fl_prim_name','fl_addr_suffix','fl_postdir','fl_unit_desig','fl_sec_range','fl_st','fl_fips_county','blk']
df['key'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '|'.join(x for x in row if x), axis=1, raw=True)
```

Comment: it seems running, however its very very slow

Comment: @llllaaa I made a modification, does that run any faster?

Comment: Based on preliminary timing, the new method should be ~ 10x faster than before.

Comment: Timing with DataFrame of shape (800000, 3): `1.77 s ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `melt` to flat your dataframe, drop null values then group by index and finally concatenate values:

```
cols = ['fl_predir', 'fl_prim_range', 'fl_prim_name', 'fl_addr_suffix' , 
        'fl_postdir', 'fl_unit_desig', 'fl_sec_range', 'fl_st', 
        'fl_fips_county', 'blk']

df['key'] = (df[cols].melt(ignore_index=False)['value'].dropna()
                     .astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg('|'.join))
```

Output:

```
>>> df['key']
0    N|911|WALLACE|AVE|MT|31|600
Name: key, dtype: object
```

**Alternative** (`Pandas < 1.1.0`)

```
df['keys'] = (df[cols].unstack().dropna().astype(str)
                      .groupby(level=1).agg('|'.join))
```

Comment: TypeError: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index

Comment: Upgrade your version of `Pandas>=1.1.0`

Comment: @llllaaa. I updated my answer. You can use `unstack` instead of `melt`. Can you check it please?

Comment: Timing with DataFrame of shape (800000, 3): `10.5 s ± 194 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: That's why you DV my answer?